# Is there any way to update the most recent version of row through SQL?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, oracle9i

I read that Oracle maintains row versions to deal with concurrency. I want to run an update query on a very big real-time database but this update job must alter the most recent version of the row.

Is this possible via PL/SQL or simply SQL?

Edited below **

Let me clear the scenario, the real-life issue that we faced on a very large database. Our client is a well-known cell phone service provider.

Our database has a table that manages records of the current balance left on the customer's cell phone account. Among the other columns of the table, one column stores the amount of recharge done and one other column manages the current active balance left.

We have two independent PL/SQL scripts. One script is automatically fired when the customer recharges his phone and updates his balance.

The second script is about deduction certain charges from the customers account. This is a batch job as it applies to all the customers. This script is scheduled to run at certain intervals of a day. When this script is run, it loads 50,000 records in the memory, updates certain columns and performs bulk update back to the table.

The issue happened is like this:

A customer, whose ID is 101, contacted his local shop to get his phone recharged. He pays the amount. But till the time his phone was about to recharge, the scheduled time of the second script fired the second script. The second script loaded the records of 50,000 customers in the memory. In this in-memory records, one of the record of this customer too.

Till the time the second script's batch update finishes, the first script successfully recharged the customer's account.

Now what happened is that is the actual table, the column: "CurrentAccountBalance" gets updated to 150, but the in-memory records on which the second script was working had the customer's old balance i.e, 100.

The second script had to deduct 10 from the column: "CurrentAccountBalance". When, according to actual working, the customer's "CurrentAccountBalance" should be 140, this issue made his balance 90.

Now how to deal with this issue.

Comment: You're talking about Flashback, Oracle's temporal access?

Comment: No. Plain SQL update statement.

Comment: You're trying to look at uncommitted data from another session? And then update it before it's committed!?

Comment: The update will always work against the last committed version of the row. I'm not sure what your issue is. Are you trying to include rows that are modified and committed after the start of the update, if you're expecting to modify a lot of data?

Comment: I shudder to think how things would work if anything *but* this was even possible...

Comment: Please check the OP for added lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is what is anyway happening if you `UPDATE`.

It is true that Oracle keeps old data for a while, but just to support consistent reads. That is, read operations that see only the state as it was at start of the transaction--even if the data was overwritten in the meantime. It's called **Multi Version Concurrency Control** and can be controlled by the **Transaction Isolation Level**.

You can explicitly request the most recent one by selecting `` `FOR UPDATE ``; that adds a lock for the record so that nobody else can update it in the meanwhile (until your transaction ends).

However, if you need to write anything (e.g., `UPDATE`) Oracle works **always** on the most recent version.

Comment: Please check the actual scenario in the OP.

Comment: I am already on the run, just skimmed through your update. that might be a race condition? So i added something about FOR UPDATE above.

Answer (score 1):

As @Markus suggested, you have a race condition. If you're loading records into memory and working on them before updating the rows in the table, and something else may try to update them in the meantime, then you need to lock them while you work on them. (I'm assuming whatever you're doing is too complicated to do a simple one-step update). Something like this would work:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c is SELECT * FROM current_balance_table FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN c LOOP
        /* Do whatever calculations you need */
        new_value := r.CurrantAccountBalance - 10;
        UPDATE current_balance_table SET CurrentAccountBalance = new_value
        WHERE CURRENT OF c;
    END LOOP:
END;
```

The problem now is that all records are locked for the duration of the loop, so your customer in the shop will either not be able to update their balance, or will have a log wait before the update takes effect - though when it does it will work on the updated value you stored. So you'd have to break the cursor up into small chunks, balancing performance of your script against the impact on anyone else trying to update the same table.

One option would be to have an outer cursor selecting all the customers you're targeting with no locking, and then an inner one that locks the balance record for that customer while that row is calculated and updated. You'd have to commit after each inner loop to release the lock for that row. This involves a lot more locking/unlocking and committing after every row update slows things down a lot. But it minimises the impact on the individual customer in the shop, as only a single row is locked at a time and the length of time that is locked is minimised. So, you need to find the right balance.

Comment: At present we are locking, but I wanted to know any efficient alternative.